Understanding the hydrogen chemical potential in transition-metal oxide redox
Recently I've been reading a paper by Ceder & coworkers about the stability of various manganese hydroxide phases under constant pH and electrode potential. In this paper, the authors derived a so-called Pourbaix grand potential to represent relative stability. I am okay with almost all of the derivation, but I got confused at one particular point and have been trapped there for long.
In their methods section, the Pourbaix potential writes
\begin{equation}
\Psi = G -\frac{\partial U}{\partial N_\ce{O}} N_\ce{O} -\frac{\partial U}{\partial N_\ce{H}} N_\ce{H} - \frac{\partial U}{\partial Q}Q.
\end{equation}
Here, the authors chose the system to contain only the $\ce{MO_{N_O}H_{N_H}^{{Q}^+}}$ species, and the aqueous environment acts as a reservoir of H, O, and electric charge Q. Then they stated as follows:

In solution, the derivative with respect to the number of hydrogen atoms is the chemical potential of a proton $μ_\ce{H^+}$ at the reference potential ($E = \pu{0 V}$ vs. SHE) minus the electric work $E$ required to bring the hydrogen atom into the phase at $E$,

and thus they obtained
\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial U}{\partial N_\ce{H}} = \mu_\ce{H^{+}} - E.
\end{equation}
In my opinion, there should be $\dfrac{\partial U}{\partial N_\ce{H}} = \mu_\ce{H}$, where $\mu_\ce{H}$ is the chemical potential of a neutral $\ce{H}$ atom. Since $\ce{H -> H^{+} + e^{-}}$, we have $\mu_\ce{H} = \mu_\ce{H^{+}} + \mu_\ce{e^{-}}$. How do we get $\dfrac{\partial U}{\partial N_\ce{H}} = \mu_{H^{+}} - E$? Do you know any reference that shows $\mu_{e^{-}} = -E$?
Much appreciated!

See also Wikipedia:  Pourbaix_diagram_for_Manganese.svg and  Wikipedia: Pourbaix diagram

Just figured out a quick explanation for $\mu_{e^-}=-E$. This might not be understood as the physical truth, but rather as an alternate way of writing down half cell Nerst equations. Here is how to derive this.
Suppose we have a full cell reaction:
\begin{equation}
A^+ + B \rightarrow A + B^+,
\end{equation}
with redox couple $A^{+}/A$ on one side of the cell, while $B^{+}/B$ in the other. The equilibrium of electrochemical potential writes
\begin{equation}
\tilde{\mu}_{A^+} + \tilde{\mu}_{B} = \tilde{\mu}_{A} + \tilde{\mu}_{B^+},
\end{equation}
where $\tilde{\mu} = \mu + z\phi$ is the electrochemical potential of a species, equivalent to its chemical potential shifted by its charge multiplied by the local electric potential. Since $z=1$, we have
\begin{equation}
\phi_A - \phi_B = (\mu_A - \mu_{A^+}) - (\mu_{B} - \mu_{B^+}),
\end{equation}
$\phi_A$ and $\phi_B$ represents the electric potential applied on $A^{+}/A$ and $B^{+}/B$ sides, respectively. Their difference represents the amount of reverse potential required to stop the battery from producing currents. Thus according to the definition of electromotive force (EMF), $\phi_A - \phi_B = -E_{AB}$.
In order to get a formula for half cells, we split the EMF as contribution from half cell A and half cell B, $E_{AB} = E_A - E_B$, and write
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
E_A = -\phi_A &= \mu_{A^+} - \mu_A; \\
E_B = -\phi_B &= \mu_{B^+} - \mu_B.
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}(1)
This is how electrochemical potentials $E_A$ and $E_B$ are defined. For a half cell at equilibrium, we should have
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\tilde{\mu}_{A^+} + \tilde{\mu}_{e^-} &= \tilde{\mu}_{A} \Leftrightarrow \\
 \mu_{A^+} + \phi_A + \mu_{e^-} - \phi_A &= \mu_A \Leftrightarrow \\
\mu_{A^+} + \mu_{e^-} &= \mu_A.
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
Compare with Equation (1), we get $\mu_{e^-} = -E_A$ on side A, and that's it.
Besides, there is a more intuitive way to derive the results in the original paper. Consider the following half reaction
$$\ce{MO_{x_1}H_{y_1}^{{q_1}^+} + a H2O + b H+ + c e- -> MO_{x_2}H_{y_2}^{{q_2}^+}},$$
in which
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
a &= x_2 - x_1 \\
b &= (y_2 - y_1) - 2(x_2 - x_1) \\
c &= -(q_2 - q_1) + (y_2 - y_1) -2(x_2 - x_1)
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
hold in order to balance charge and mass. Use notation $\mu_{\ce{e-}} = -E$, The equilibrium condition writes
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\mu_2 = \mu_1 + a \mu_{\ce{H2O}} &+ b \mu_{\ce{H+}} + c \mu_{\ce{e-}} \\
\Leftrightarrow \Psi_2 &= \Psi_1, \\
\Psi_1 &= \mu_1 - x_1 \mu_{\ce{H2O}} + (2 x_1 - y_1) \mu_{\ce{H+}} - (2 x_1 - y_1 + q_1) E \\
\Psi_2 &= \mu_2 - x_2 \mu_{\ce{H2O}} + (2 x_2 - y_2) \mu_{\ce{H+}} - (2 x_2 - y_2 + q_2) E. \\
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
Where $\mu_1$ and $\mu_2$ equals to the molar Gibbs energy of phase 1 ($\ce{MO_{x_1}H_{y_1}^{{q_1}^+}}$) and phase 2 ($\ce{MO_{x_2}H_{y_2}^{{q_2}^+}}$) to When $\Psi_2 > \Psi_1$, the reaction moves backward, phase 1 is stable. When $\Psi_2 = \Psi_1$, phase 1 and 2 can co-exist. When $\Psi_2 < \Psi_1$, the reaction moves forward, and phase 2 is stable. We have obtained $\Psi$ exactly as the Pourbaix potential mentioned in the original paper, except that we ignored the normalization requirement to divide by $n_M$, when the numbers of M per formula are not equal on the two phases.
